# Passing route as argument in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm kinda new to flutter and i'm trying to get two buttons on my page and make them send the user to different pages on my app. Right now I have this code for my buttons, but to make it work, I just change the last part of the code from SearchPage() to ScanPage() and this seems to be inefficient. Can I somehow pass in the pages as arguements for the button widgets?

```
// Button for scanPage
Widget _buttonScan(String text, Color splashColor, Color highlightColor,
    Color fillColor, Color textColor) {
  return RaisedButton(
    highlightElevation: 0.0,
    splashColor: splashColor,
    highlightColor: highlightColor,
    elevation: 0.0,
    color: fillColor,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
    child: Text(
      text,
      style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: textColor, fontSize: 20),
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScanPage()),
      );
    },
  );
}

// Button for searchPage
Widget _buttonSearch(String text, Color splashColor, Color highlightColor,
    Color fillColor, Color textColor) {
  return RaisedButton(
    highlightElevation: 0.0,
    splashColor: splashColor,
    highlightColor: highlightColor,
    elevation: 0.0,
    color: fillColor,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
    child: Text(
      text,
      style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: textColor, fontSize: 20),
    ),
    onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SearchPage()),
            );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to share your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My bad. It's my first time here. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: You are doing it correctly. You can also use routes, but one is not necessarily better than the other, to my knowledge. It's more about re-usability. If you have a route that needs to be accessed throughout your app and it doesn't need parameters passed to it, or you are using some state management that will take of them, then you can use the route definition on the routes of of your MaterialApp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function as an argument to your widget that will take care of the navigation direction. In your case, either go to scanPage or searchPage, like this:

```
Widget _buttonScan(String text, Color splashColor, Color highlightColor,
Color fillColor, Color textColor, Widget Function() choosePage) {
return RaisedButton(
highlightElevation: 0.0,
splashColor: splashColor,
highlightColor: highlightColor,
elevation: 0.0,
color: fillColor,
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
child: Text(
  text,
  style: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: textColor, fontSize: 20),
),
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => choosePage()),
  );
},
);
}
```

And when you call it:

```
_buttonScan(...,() => ScanPage ()) //To go to ScanPage
_buttonScan(...,() => SearchPage()) //To go to SearchPage
```

Comment: I might just have misunderstood you but how would I make it so that I can reuse my button code for different buttons that send the user to different pages? Right now there is two pages I want to send the user to. SearchPage and ScanPage.

Comment: I don't think there is another way of doing this. The typical way of traversing pages is by using Navigator.

Comment: @Khal oh wait you mean the Button widget is repeated and you want to call this widget twice for multiple functionalities?

Comment: So I want to use the same button twice on my front page. So two buttons but I want one of them to send the user to my ScanPage and on of them to my SearchPage. The buttons are just for choosing if you want to open camera and scan or use the search page I made for the app. If that makes sense.

Comment: As you can see in the code. The only difference between those two widgets, is that they send the user to different pages. I feel like it's a lot of duplicate code for only that.

Comment: Yes I gotcha. here's how you can do it. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

To pass arguments you need to use **named routes** of the `Navigator` like this :

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
  context,
  ExtractArgumentsScreen.routeName,
  arguments: ScreenArguments(
    'Extract Arguments Screen',
    'This message is extracted in the build method.',
  ),
);
```

[See the official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)